# Arcpy.CopyFeatures_management creates empty feature class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, feature-class, copy

I am trying to iteratively copy selection layers to new feature classes. My script successfully creates the new feature classes, but they are empty. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

targetCounties = ['Harlan', 'Bell']

minesFC = "Ky_Permitted_Mine_Boundaries"

createdShapefiles = []

for targetCounty in targetCounties:
    
    countyQuery = "Ky_Permitted_Mine_Statistics.COUNTY_1 = '" + str(targetCounty.upper()) + "'"
    
    countyLayer = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(minesFC, "NEW_SELECTION", countyQuery)
    
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(countyLayer, str(targetCounty) + "_Co_Mines")
    
    createdShapefiles.append(str(targetCounty) + "_Co_Mines")
```

Comment: What type of spatial data are you working with (shp, FGDB,etc)? Can you confirm by doing “print(countyQuery)” that the attribute from the print statement actually exists?

Comment: Your Selection will be wrong. If nothing satisfies your query, you'll select nothing, making an empty feature class. Run the Select by Attribute tool inside ArcGIS Pro, get the Python syntax from a successful selection and update your code.

Comment: @Aaron print(countyQuery) yields "Ky_Permitted_Mine_Statistics.COUNTY_1 = 'BELL'", which to my understanding should be correct (assuming 'BELL" is a target county)

Comment: @KHibma I ripped the county query syntax straight from a successful selection in ArcGIS Pro; that is why I am stumped currently.

Comment: I think it is something to do with the fact that I am selecting from a field that was joined to the table. If I do the selection and copyFeatures with any native field from the table, it works. Any ideas for how to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered it's an issue with trying to do a selection of a joined field via Python, which apparently is a known difficulty with ArcGIS Pro. I decided to calculate native fields from the joined fields and it worked for me.